# PDO - Query executed twice?

Tags: php, mysql

**My solution**

I was debugging my functions on index.php, i didn't notice that my browser was searching for favicon.icon. Currently my router sends the user to index.php if the requested file isn't found, this cause the seccond trigger.

You can easly find this @ you're site acces logs!

*Sorry for my grammer, i hope its readable..

**Topic**

I have created a  little database script, there is only one thing i cannot solve. When i execute a insert query it wil execute twice. The values are diffrent(Value = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes).

```
    private function __init($Query = '', $Params = NULL){
    if($this->__getStatus() === false){
        $this->__createConnection();
    }
    $this->__PQuery = $this->__Database->prepare($Query);
        foreach($Params as $param => $value){
            $dataType = PDO::PARAM_STR;
            switch ($value){
                case is_int($value):
                     $dataType = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $dataType = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
                case is_null($value):
                    $dataType = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
        }
    $this->__PQuery->bindValue($param, $value, $dataType);
    }
    $this->__PQuery->execute();
}
```

Function call:

```
$this->__database->Query("INSERT INTO `Serials` (`SerialKey`, `Active`, `ActivatedOn`, `ValidTo`, `Paid`) VALUES (:Serial, 'no', NULL, NULL, 'no');", ['Serial' => openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(10)]);
```

(Query send it to __init)

Can you guys give me any idea's where to look? I'm searching for about 4 hours now.

Backtrace before execution

> Core\Database\Handler->__init(INSERT INTO `Serials` (`SerialKey`, `Active`, `ActivatedOn`, `ValidTo`, `Paid`) VALUES (:Serial, 'no', NULL, NULL, 'no');, Array ([Serial] => ��n�� �R)) called at [PATH_TO_PUBLIC_HTMLpublic_html/Core/Database/Handler.php:45]
>     Core\Database\Handler->Query(INSERT INTO `Serials` (`SerialKey`, `Active`, `ActivatedOn`, `ValidTo`, `Paid`) VALUES (:Serial, 'no', NULL, NULL, 'no');, Array ([Serial] => ��n�� �R)) called at [PATH_TO_PUBLIC_HTMLpublic_html/Core/serialManager/createSerial.php:17]
>     Core\serialManager\createSerial->__storeToDB() called at [PATH_TO_PUBLIC_HTMLpublic_html/Core/serialManager/createSerial.php:9]
>     Core\serialManager\createSerial->__construct() called at [PATH_TO_PUBLIC_HTMLpublic_html/Controllers/Website.php:6]
>     Website->Home()
>     call_user_func_array(Array ([0] => Website Object (),[1] => Home), Array ()) called at [PATH_TO_PUBLIC_HTMLpublic_html/Core/Routing/Router.php:20]
>     Core\Routing\Router->__construct() called at [PATH_TO_PUBLIC_HTMLpublic_html/index.php:3]

Backtrace after execution

> Core\Database\Handler->__init(INSERT INTO `Serials` (`SerialKey`, `Active`, `ActivatedOn`, `ValidTo`, `Paid`) VALUES (:Serial, 'no', NULL, NULL, 'no');, Array ([Serial] => F�7�,.Kr�)) called at [PATH_TO_PUBLIC_HTMLpublic_html/Core/Database/Handler.php:45]
>     Core\Database\Handler->Query(INSERT INTO `Serials` (`SerialKey`, `Active`, `ActivatedOn`, `ValidTo`, `Paid`) VALUES (:Serial, 'no', NULL, NULL, 'no');, Array ([Serial] => F�7�,.Kr�)) called at [PATH_TO_PUBLIC_HTMLpublic_html/Core/serialManager/createSerial.php:17]
>     Core\serialManager\createSerial->__storeToDB() called at [PATH_TO_PUBLIC_HTMLpublic_html/Core/serialManager/createSerial.php:9]
>     Core\serialManager\createSerial->__construct() called at [PATH_TO_PUBLIC_HTMLpublic_html/Controllers/Website.php:6]
>     Website->Home()
>     call_user_func_array(Array ([0] => Website Object (),[1] => Home), Array ()) called at [PATH_TO_PUBLIC_HTMLpublic_html/Core/Routing/Router.php:20]
>     Core\Routing\Router->__construct() called at [PATH_TO_PUBLIC_HTMLpublic_html/index.php:3]

[NOTE] My hosting company are under attack..

*Sorry for my grammer, did my best..

Comment: Code validated @ other server; code is 100% working? Can a ddos/attack cause this problem?

Comment: A DDOS can expose race conditions you didn't know you had. It doesn't create bugs, it exposes them. If you want to block duplicates either set up a `UNIQUE` index to prevent them, or have some kind of [idempotency system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) in place to ensure the second call isn't triggered.

Comment: is db gets twice entry? or you saying it by just looking at traces?

Comment: You need to provide more code. It could be that `$this->__database->Query()` is calling it twice or calling another function that is calling `__init()` a second time.

Comment: Fixed, added fix to topic :)

Comment: @RomanoSchoonheim Interesting solution. Please add your solution as an answer, so you can accept this and we can upvote it.

Comment: @AbcAeffchen Added my solution to this topic! (Iknow its late)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Cause of the problem**

My browser was looking for favicon.ico, but it didnt exist. If a file/page didnt exist the request is routed to index.php

**Mistake**

- Debugging on index.php
- Missing favicon.ico

**What did i learned?**

- Never debug on the homepage, see below why.
- If there are 2 requests are incomming(when 1 made) Probably the browser sends the second request to look for the favicon.ico (In my case if the page doenst exist return to home)

**Solution**

**1** Don't debug on you're index.php

**2** Add the following code to you're html

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
```

**Sorry For My Broken English**